# Як краще попросити насипати/продати щось "с походом"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian, фразеологізми, соціолінгвістика

У російського іменника **поход** є друге [значення](http://alfavit.dljavseh.ru/souz/p3.htm)

> **ПОХОД**, -а,м. (разг.). Небольшой излишек в весе товара. Взвесить с
>   походом.

Часто чую

> А **поход** будет? 
>   Я сделаю вам с хорошим **походом**. 
>   А на **поход** не дадите?

Українське [похід](http://sum.in.ua/s/pokhid) не має такого значення. Значення немає, а ***походу*** хочеться :)

Російсько-український словник сталих виразів [пропонує](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/search.php?fullname=%EF%EE%F5%EE%E4&submit=%D8%F3%EA%E0%F2%E8)

> З **лишком** (з **надлишком**, іноді з **потягом**), без лишку (без потягу).

Можливо є менш прямолінійний вираз. Що використовують на західній Україні?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Усталеного словникового слова чи словосполучення, напевне, не існує. Але є декілька варіантів, які можуть підходити у конкретних випадках — частіш за все, у жартівливому контексті.

Словники пропонують декілька варіантів перекладу <sub>рос.</sub> [*лишек*](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) та <sub>рос.</sub> [*лихва*](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%9B%D0%B8%CC%81%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0&scope=rusb&no_accents=&main_only=on&highlight=on):

- [*з надда́тком*](http://sum.in.ua/s/naddatok), *в наддаток*

  > *Замісто горобця я з'їм жуків десяток Да гусені, черви десятків три **в наддаток*** (Євген Гребінка, I, 1957, 46).

  Щоправда, це саме слово використовується також у контексті надмірної віддяки чи лихварства (<sub>рос.</sub> *ростовщичество*):

  > *Другий мій брат поїхав у Перу і вбився там у велике багатство гроші, що він нам звідти присилав, не тільки **повернули з наддатком** частину майна, що на нього при поділі припала, а й дала можливість батькові знову стати щедрим…* — ["Премудрий гідальго Дон Кіхот з Ламанчі"](http://bukvoid.com.ua/library/migel_de_servantes_saavedra/premudriy_gidalgo_don_kihot_z_lamanchi/155.html) у перекладі [Миколи Лукаша](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%88_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)
- *з на́спою*, *з верхо́м* (про сипучі предмети)

  > Брав ущерть, а віддав **з на́спою** (словник Грінченка)
- *з по́тягом*

  > Тут добрих два фунти ще й **з по́тягом** (Київ)
- *з на́дтом* (жартівливе)
- *з чо́хом* (жартівливе)

Особисто я чув (на Київщині) вирази *з чохом* та *з походом*.